# Can an iPhone be SSH'd without jailbreaking it?

Tags: ssh, terminal, iphone

I had my iPhone jailbroken and used *MobileTerminal* all the time. But I just wanted to go back to normal, and I have an app now that allows me to SSH to other computers.

Is there a way to SSH to my phone? I have its IP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSH server won't start without jailbreaking it.

You could probably use an app you developed or that you can run using a developer license, which will start the SSH on a port you want (pretending to test it).

Comment: do you know where I could find the code to do that? Honestly, I don't know much C#...

Comment: you could try packaging the application and start the server . There are few apps which start listening on port > 1024 to act as a server when communicating with Mac (like 1Password when its in sync mode) , you could try similarly. I am not a Obj C programmer myself.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** You can't.

In order to be able to connect to the (or any, for that matter) phone via SSH, it needs to run an SSH server that listens for connections. Although the iPhone theoretically can, Apple does not ship an SSH server by default (or at least doesn't enable it, not too sure).

This is why you need to jailbreak the phone and install your own SSH server.

Also see this Stack Overflow question:

> #### [How to read iPhone files without jailbreaking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445579/how-to-read-iphone-files-without-jailbreaking)
>
> I'd like to access files in an iPhone, such as using remotely
>   connecting via ssh and telnet. But it appears that the iPhone's ssh or
>   telnet are not supported. I can ping it, but cannot use telnet or ssh.